# How to make the jQuery plugin Autocomplete like Google replace results?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, autocomplete, jquery-autocomplete

I'm using the jQuery plugin [Autocomplete like Google](http://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/autocomplete/#visibleLimit) for two form fields -- `foo` and `bar` (that depends on `foo`):

```
$(function() {
    $("#foo").autocomplete({
        minLength: 3,
        limit: 5,
        source : [{
            url:"/my/ajax/controller/foo?data[foo_number]=%QUERY%",
            type:'remote'
        }],  
    });
});

$(function() {
    $("#bar").autocomplete({
        minLength: 3,
        limit: 5,
        source : [
            function(query, add) {
                fooNumber = $('#foo-number').val();
                $.getJSON("/my/ajax/controller/bar?data[number]=" + query + "&data[foo_name]=" + fooNumber, function(response) {
                    add(response);
                })
        }],  
    });
});
```

It works basically, but there is an issue with the field `bar`. Every further result of the autocomplete AJAX request is *added* to the last one and doesn't *replace* it. This leads to 1. duplicated antries and 2. outdated entries, when e.g. the current AJAX request hasn't got any new results and the list retrieved for the last request is displayed.

What is wrong at my code? **How to get every time only the results, that has jsut been retrieved?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The option I needed calls [`appendMethod`](http://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/autocomplete/#appendMethod):

```
$(function() {
    $("#bar").autocomplete({
        minLength: 3,
        limit: 5,
        appendMethod:'replace',
        source : [
            function(query, add) {
                fooNumber = $('#foo-number').val();
                $.getJSON("/my/ajax/controller/bar?data[number]=" + query + "&data[foo_name]=" + fooNumber, function(response) {
                    add(response);
                })
        }],  
    });
});
```